# No passcode if at home?

Tags: iphone, password, geolocation

Is there a way to set up the iPhone so that when I'm away from home it requires a lock code, but when I'm at home I don't need a passcode?

Comment: Good idea. Submit it to Apple here: http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the basic functionality does not provide this feature.

You can do this by Jaibreaking your device (getting write priviligies to system partition) and installing tweaks like :

- [AutoProtect](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2012/05/10/autoprotect/)
- [CleverPin](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2011/04/18/cleverpin-for-the-iphone-is-an-innovative-way-to-balance-ease-of-use-with-passcode-security/)